# argparse is exiting if no argument is parsed

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse and some of the arguments require a value.
For example, in my arguments

```
lst -pln -pk
```

lst sotore true, -pln also store true value,
but -pk requires a value to be entered.

When I enter `-pk` without a value, it shows the following error and exits.

***error: argument -pk/--package: expected one argument***

But I don't want the program to exit. Instead, I want to show an invalid input error message and continue the while loop in my program.

Note: In my program, I used a while loop to continue the program until the user enters exit and press enter. It works fine.

Comment: You can pass `exit_on_error=False` to the constructor of `argparse.ArgumentParser`.

Comment: Or change the `error/exit` methods of the parser.

Comment: Usually `input` is small, and doesn't need the complex `argparse` parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nargs="?"`.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> ArgumentParser objects usually associate a single command-line argument with a single action to be taken. The `nargs` keyword argument associates a different number of command-line arguments with a single action. The supported values are:
>
> - (...)
> - `'?'`. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the value from default will be produced.

Example:

```py
$ cat test.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-pk", nargs="?")
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

```sh
$ python3 test.py -pk 123
Namespace(pk='123')
```

```sh
$ python3 test.py -pk
Namespace(pk=None)
```